# having trouble downloading Wget for windows

Tags: wget

I have tried to download Wget from https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/ but it does not open. Well, after it is downloaded then it will open-after clicking it several times-but if I try to type something or move the terminal then the terminal will just shut off/exit out. This is for windows and I have downloaded the latest version in an EXE format. I am not sure if this is the correct way to download these items. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please open terminal where `wget.exe` is located and then do

```
wget.exe http://www.example.com
```

if it is working it should download [example domain site](http://www.example.com/)